# Calendar Prev/Next buttons linking to wrong dates

Tags: views, datetime

In the calendar month display for August with the path `calendar/2015-08`, the forward and next page buttons offer the user a link to October -- completely jumping over September straight to October.

[image]

That is, the Next link in the above picture jumps straight to 
`calendar/2015-10`.

I'm at a loss. I've tried cycling Ajax in the view which did nothing.

I'm running the following modules:

```
$ drush pml | grep calendar
 Date/Time  Calendar (calendar)               Module  Enabled        7.x-3.5   
 FullCalen  FullCalendar (fullcalendar)       Module  Enabled        7.x-2.0   
 dar        (fullcalendar_colors)                                              
 dar        (fullcalendar_legend)                                              
 dar        (fullcalendar_options)
```

And I see the this view is rendered in the `./sites/all/modules/date/date_views/theme/date-views-pager.tpl.php`

```
<?php if (!empty($next_url)) : ?>
 49       <li class="date-next">
 50         <?php print l(($mini ? '' : t('Next', array(), array('context' => 'date_nav')) . ' ') . '&raquo;', $next_url, $next_options); ?>
 51       </li>
 52     <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drush dl date --select 
Choose one of the available releases for date:
 [0]  :  Cancel                                                
 [1]  :  7.x-2.x-dev  -  2015-Jun-16  -  Development           
 [2]  :  7.x-2.9-rc1  -  2015-Mar-27  -  Supported             
 [3]  :  7.x-2.8      -  2014-Jul-29  -  Recommended, Security 
 [4]  :  7.x-1.x-dev  -  2013-Sep-30  -  Development
```

So if I have 7.x-2.8 - It's okay.   7.x-2.9-rc1 or  7.x-2.x-dev  both jump ahead by two months.drush dl date --select

Of the ones available, dev and rc1 have an issue with the next button. 2.8 is fine but it defaults the calendar name to include the first day of the month. So you must choose between a bad title format or a bad next button.

**My solution:** I moved back to Date 7.x-2.8 and then overrode `date-views-pager.tpl.php` in my theme with the following:

```
<div class="date-nav-wrapper clearfix<?php if (!empty($extra_classes)) print $extra_classes; ?>">
  <div class="date-nav item-list">
    <div class="date-heading">
      <h3><?php
        print date("F", strtotime($nav_title))
            . ' '
            . date("Y", strtotime($nav_title));
        ?>
      </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue, with some patches you might consider using.  I'd recommend sticking to 7.x-2.8 unless 7.x-2.9 fixed something you need fixed.

See: [Calendar block Next/Prev navigation broken](http://drupal.org/node/2375235)

Some of the initial patches fix the monthly navigation but break the weekly navigation, so the patch needs work.  If you have time to fix it yourself, please do!  Date module needs a lot more people contributing than it has right now.